# laradock_mysql won't start and exits(1)

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laradock

When i'm composing up from my laradock folder. All services start except from mysql. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vshe7.png)

I have restored my docker to default settings but mysql keeps exiting. My error say's i'm setting a value. But i don't even have a database. So that confuses me.

> ERROR: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
>   mysql_1                | command was: "mysqld --verbose --help"
>   mysql_1                |
>   mysql_1                | 2018-05-07T16:24:32.727143Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
>   mysql_1                | 2018-05-07T16:24:32.727230Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'
>   mysql_1                | 2018-05-07T16:24:32.729063Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

Answer (score 0):

- edited `laradock/.env`,set MYSQL_VERSION from latest to 5.7
- deleted `~/.laradock/mysql/` directory completely (Warning, This may delete your data ! )
- then rebuild docker-compose build mysql
- docker-compose up -d mysql as usual

Hope this helps :)